# Evaluate the integral $\int\limits_1^e {{{\ln x} \over {x\ln (x + 2)}}dx} $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate:$$\int\limits_1^e {{{\ln x} \over {x\ln (x + 2)}}dx} $$

This was what I did:
\begin{array}{l}\displaystyle{
\int\limits_1^e {\frac{{\ln x}}{{x\ln (x + 2)}}dx} \\
 = \int\limits_1^e {\frac{{\ln x}}{{x\ln x \cdot \ln 2}}dx} \\
 = \int\limits_1^e {\frac{1}{{x\ln 2}}dx} \\
 = \left. {\frac{{\ln x}}{{\ln 2}}} \right|_1^e\\
 = \frac{1}{{\ln 2}}}
\end{array}
However, after checking on WolframAlpha, it took so much time to load without any solution given, it seems that WolframAlpha cannot solve this.

Is my solution correct? Otherwise what is wrong with it?

Comment: Where do you find this integral? It seems interesting. I will take a try

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln(a+b) \ne \ln a \cdot \ln b.$$

For example, do you really think that $\ln 3 = \ln 1 \cdot\ln 2$?

What is correct is $\ln a + \ln b = \ln(ab)$: i.e logarithms turn multiplication into addition.

Comment: Oh well, I did I big mistake there. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, we all make dumb mistakes sometimes. Definitely go back and revise this topic.